# use a file-upload in a wysiwyg editor

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload, textangular

I'm looking for a wysiwyg editor that can use the ng-file-upload module. Is there someone who can give some feed-back about a such use ?

Or any other angularjs text editor that can be customized to define a file upload management.

thanks

Edit: I would need a crop image tool for upload

Comment: Lots of editors around with integrated upload. Asking for recommendations is off-topic here

Comment: yes but the ng-file-upload is the best custumizable tool, and there isn't a lot of wysiwyg tool that can use it... Else I found a tool TextAngular, I think this should be a good choice .

Comment: well sometimes you have to adapt. Can use any editor around...just wrap it in directive if one doesn't already exist

Comment: yes but editing a wysiwyg tool isn't a good pratice in my mind, more if you want to avoid too much effort to maintain an apps up to date. Also wrapping is a good practice but I'm afraid on the time lost to maintain the wrap after updating the main tool

Comment: no need to edit it...just extend it or use plugins within it.

Comment: Anyway thanks - I will look on TextAngular, it seems that can do my work, but the problem is that the documentation is missing on upload feature